# Использование файлов ресурсов (сателитных сборок) в SQL-CLR-проекте

Tags: sql, .net, resources, sqlclr

Можно ли использовать ресурные сборки (*.resources.dll) в проекте SQL-CLR? Если да, то как?

Пишу одну SQL-CLR-процедуру, в которой через входной параметр хочу явно задавать язык, на котором генерируются выходные данные.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался сам, поэтому представляю свое решение:

В SQL-CLR-проект добавить ресурсы у меня не получилось, поэтому создаем отдельный проект .net - простую библиотечную сборку, например - MyDatabaseResources.

Добавляем в нее необходимые ресурсы на разных языках - файлы *.resx. У меня это например файлы: myres.resx (по умолчанию), myres.en.resx, myres.ru.resx .. и т.д.

Во время сборки проекта создается основная библиотека и в подкаталогах en, de, ru .. сателитные сборки - "MyDatabaseResources.resources.dll". На SQL сервере нет понятия подкаталога, поэтому нужно слить все файлы в одну категорию, при этом сателитные сборки переименовываются по следующему принципу: MyDatabaseResources.resources.en.dll, MyDatabaseResources.resources.de.dll, MyDatabaseResources.resources.ru.dll ..

В проекте базы данных добавляем ссылки на все файлы проекта ресурсов (основной  файл и сателитные). При этом добавлять сателитные сборки нужно по одному, при этом необходимо их переименовывать соответствующим образом, потому что студия определяет их под их первоначальным именем "MyDatabaseResources.resources.dll".
Для этого в свойствах файла "Assemblyname" из "MyDatabaseResources.resources.dll" делаем "MyDatabaseResources.resources.EN.dll". Под этим именем сборка будет зарегистрирована на SQL сервере. Но в студии в списке ссылаемых сборок этот файл останется под старым именем. Что бы мочь добавить следующие сателитные сборки эту ссылку нужно также переименовать. Для этого открываем файл проекта "*.sqlproj", находим тег

```
.. Reference Include="MyDatabaseResources.resources.dll" ..
```

, который ссылается на сборку "EN" и переименовыем сслку в

```
.. Reference Include="MyDatabaseResources.resources.EN.dll" ..
```

После перегрузки проекта в студии имена будут отображаться коректно.

После создания проекта, все необходимые сборки будут зарегестрированы в базе данных SQL серевера. Процедура которая использует локализованные ресурсы может выглядеть так:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static SqlInt32 SqlStoredProcedure1(SqlString lang)
{

    if (lang.ToString() == "de") {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
    }
    else if (lang.ToString() == "fr") {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    }
    else if (lang.ToString() == "ru") {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    }
    else if (lang.ToString() == "" /*default*/) {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }

    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(lang.ToString());
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(MyDatabaseResources.Resource1.a);

    return new SqlInt32(0);
}
```